# Grep for 2 words after pattern found

Tags: linux, grep

The scenario is  i have a file and contains a string "the date and time is  2012-12-07 17:11:50"

I had searched and found a command

```
grep 'the date and time is' 2012-12-07.txt | cut -d\   -f5
```

it just displays the 5th word and i need the combination of 5th and 6th, so i tried

```
grep 'the date and time is' 2012-12-07.txt | cut -d\   -f5 -f6
```

But its error.

Now, how to grep the 5th and 6th word with one command

I just need the output like `2012-12-07 17:11:50`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess its not 5th and 6th instead its 6th and 7th

```
grep 'the date and time is' 2012-12-07.txt |awk '{print $6,$7}'
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use

```
$ grep 'the date and time is' 2012-12-07.txt | cut -d' ' -f6-7
```

Check [the man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cut) for the syntax of the `-f` option's argument.

Comment: grep 'the date and time is' 2012-12-07.txt | cut -d' ' -f5-7 Is exact for my requirement. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a job for `awk`, which is *possibly* marginally faster than constructing a pipeline consisting of multiple processes:

```
pax> echo 'hello
           the date and time is 2012-12-07 17:11:50
           goodbye' | awk '/the date and time is/ {print $6" "$7}'
2012-12-07 17:11:50
```

It combines the search and the modification in one single command.

Keep in mind that this solution, like yours, won't help if there is stuff on the line *before* your search string but `awk` can be made to do that as well, depending on the complexity of your needs, such as:

```
pax> echo 'hello
           Today (Friday), the date and time is 2012-12-07 17:11:50
           goodbye' | awk '/the date and time is/ {
                               sub (".*is","",$0);
                               print $1" "$2
                               }'
2012-12-07 17:11:50
```